# dynamic with loop for i to n, adds rows but does not cover full range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dynamic

I have a macro, that start from i, and ends at n. n is the end of the dynamic range. The macro adds rows and enters data based on various criterias. The code works very fine, but it only covers 85% of the total range before 'n' ends.
see code below:

```
Sub AddExtrasFerry()

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

n = Sheets("Original").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Original").Select

For i = 10 To n

    If Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 3).Value Like "Wood*" And Cells(i, 16).Value = 100 Then
        Cells(i + 1, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = 100
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 20430
        Cells(i + 1, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = ""

    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 3).Value Like "Wood*" And Cells(i, 16).Value > 100 Then
        Cells(i + 1, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = 100
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 20430
        Cells(i + 1, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = ""

        Cells(i + 2, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 2, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 2, 6).Value = Cells(i, 16).Value - 100
        Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = 20305
        Cells(i + 2, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 2, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 2, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 2, 16).Value = ""

        i = i + 1
        n = Sheets("Original").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i + 1, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = Cells(i, 16).Value
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 20305
        Cells(i + 1, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = ""
        i = i + 1
        n = Sheets("Original").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You insert a row in your first if block but you don't redefine n. You need to redefine n like you do in the other blocks. Also you need to increment i. Also in the second block you need to increment i by 2 as you add two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add or delete rows you need to loop backwards or you'll mess up your indexing, try this:

```
Sub AddExtrasFerry()

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

n = Sheets("Original").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Original").Select

For i = n To 10 step - 1

    If Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 3).Value Like "Wood*" And Cells(i, 16).Value = 100 Then
        Cells(i + 1, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = 100
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 20430
        Cells(i + 1, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = ""

    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 3).Value Like "Wood*" And Cells(i, 16).Value > 100 Then
        Cells(i + 1, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = 100
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 20430
        Cells(i + 1, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = ""

        Cells(i + 2, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 2, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 2, 6).Value = Cells(i, 16).Value - 100
        Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = 20305
        Cells(i + 2, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 2, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 2, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 2, 16).Value = ""

    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i + 1, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = Cells(i, 16).Value
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 20305
        Cells(i + 1, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = ""
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tom, this failed after about 20 mintues saying "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other application"

Comment: You dont need to keep redefining n if you are iterating backwards

Comment: Thanks, i removed the increments of i and removed n. It works

Comment: @mo.h No problem, you can accept the answer by clicking the green tick next to the question :)